# Remove /index.php/ from URLs on Virtual Host on Laravel app

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a Laravel app on localhost that works, there is no /index.php/ because of the .htaccess file, I guess.

But for certains reasons I had to use a virtual host from Apache2 that I have called "website.dev" and now the /index.php/ string appaers in all my URLs

Can you help please ?

I tried this :

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: "I have called `website.dev`" - Have you configured this using HTTPS? The entire `.dev` TLD is included in the HSTS preload-list so any `.dev` hostname can only be served over HTTPS. "I tried this :" - Where exactly have you added that? Presumably `/var/www/html` is the defined `DocumentRoot`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: They would already have something like that in `.htaccess` (which resolved the issue on localhost). However, it would seem the `.htaccess` file is not being processed.